# Cannot invoke toFixed(int) on the primitive type double

Tags: java, server-side, typeerror, primitive-types, tofixed

I'm currently having difficulty getting my output results from my first condition testing to be rounded to the 2nd decimal place. When the quant is equal to 5, and it is multiplied by either of the two choices, the result comes out to a number with 6+ spaces right of the decimal point. When I try to attach the .toFixed to anything, it states that it cannot apply toFixed(int) to the primitive type double, even when I place a new string variable linking to the double.

I'm just trying to get the output rounded to the 2nd decimal point. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE!!!
Thanks to muzahidbechara for the assist. His suggestion of placing the code

```js
String result = String.valueOf(new BigDecimal(calc).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP));
```

After some flopping around, I found out with additional help from muzahidbechara that the code needed to be brought down since there is an order of precedence that I didn't know about.

So thanks again to muzahidbechara for the help. If anybody else had this kind of trouble, please up vote his answer.

I placed the code in the .jsp file below so you can see where I put it. The overall output isn't complete yet (as far as the html code is concerned) is something I'll be working on tomorrow.

**My HTML File that I place in my Tomcat webapp/root folder**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!--
            Name: Student
            Date: 07APR16
            Program Description: Movie Rental Scenario
        -->

        <style>
            body {font-family:arial;}

            table.inner {border:2px solid black;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;background-color:rgb(128,170,255);}

            table.outer {border:2px solid black;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;}

            th {font-weight:normal;font-variant:small-caps;}

            input {background-color:rgb(204,230,255);}

            input.number {text-align:center;}

            p.top {font-weight:bold;font-size:15px;font-variant:small-caps;}

            p.bottom {text-align:"center";font-weight:bold;font-style:italic;font-size:15px;}

            input.footer {margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto}

            h5 {text-decoration:underline;}

            h5.misc1 {margin:0px 0px -10px 0px;}

            h5.misc2 {margin:0px 0px -20px 0px;}


        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
                <table class="outer" cellpadding="10px" border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>
        <form method="post" action="videorental.jsp">
        <p class="top">Please provide contact information in the fields below</p>
            <table class="inner" cellpadding="10px" border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="Firstname" required />
                        <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Lastname" required /><br />
                        <br />
                        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="email@example.net" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" title="The email address you entered is invalid, please check to ensure you're using a valid email address that fits the formate email@example.net" style="width:288px;" required /><br />
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br />
        <p class="bottom">Please provide additional information below</p>
            <table class="inner" cellpadding="10px" border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>
                    <h5 class="misc1">Number of movies to rent</h5><br />
                    <input class="number" type="text" name="quant" placeholder="##" pattern="[0-9]{1,2}" title="Please input a number between 1-99" style="width:20px" required/><br />
                    <br />
                    <h5 class="misc2">Which type of movie<h5>
                    <input type="radio" id="type" name="type" value="1" required />DVD (Cost per: $2.99)<br />
                    <input type="radio" id="type" name="type" value="2" required />Blu-ray (Cost per: $3.99)<br />
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br />
                <input class="footer" type="submit" value="Submit" />
                <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
                                    </th>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**My Server Side Javascript File that I place in my Tomcat webapp/root folder**

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>

        body {font-family:arial;}

        table {border:2px solid black;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;background-color:rgb(128,170,255);}

        th {font-weight:normal;font-variant:small-caps;padding-left:500px;text-align:right;}

        td {text-align:center;}

    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <%
        /*
            Name: Student
            Date: 07APR16
            Program Description: Movie Rental Scenario
        */

        //Received Data

        String first = request.getParameter("fname");
        String last = request.getParameter("lname");
        String mail = request.getParameter("email");

        double num1 = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("quant"));
        byte choice = Byte.parseByte(request.getParameter("type"));

        double calc = 0.0;
        double answer = 0.0;

        // Condition Testing 1
        if (choice == 1)
        {
            calc = num1 * 2.99;
        }
        else if (choice == 2)
        {
            calc = num1 * 3.99;
        }

        // Condition Testing 2

        if (choice == 1)
        {
            answer = 2.99;
        }
        else if (choice == 2)
        {
            answer = 3.99;
        }

        String result = String.valueOf(new java.math.BigDecimal(calc).setScale(2, java.math.BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP));

        //Display Results

        out.print("First-name  = " + first);
        out.print("Last-name = " + last);
        out.println("<BR>");
        out.print("Email Address = " + mail);
        out.println("<table border=1>");
        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<th>");
        out.print("Price for type of rental:<td>" + answer);
        out.println("</td>");
        out.println("</th>");
        out.println("</tr>");
        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<th>");
        out.print("Number of movies to rent:<td>" + num1);
        out.println("</td>");
        out.println("</th>");
        out.println("</tr>");
        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<th>");
        out.println("<td>");
        out.println("==========");
        out.println("</td>");
        out.println("</th>");
        out.println("</tr>");
        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<th>");
        out.print("Total:<td>" + result);
        out.println("</td>");
        out.println("</th>");
        out.println("</tr>");
        out.println("</table>");
    %>
</body>
```

Comment: If I remove the "String result = calc.toFixed(2)" from the javascript file, I get no errors, but the output is not rounded the way I want. the reason said String result is in the script is one of many different things I tried to get the rounding to work. So if you remove said String result, the javascript file will be back to how I had it before trying to implement the toFixed(int).

Comment: Shouldn't this be labeled as "Java" and not "javascript"?

Comment: I didn't look through the entire code yet, but maybe you should try casting it to a double (or int)

Comment: Sorry Mottie, I'm still a bit new to writing and implementing javascript into my html documents. I'm linking .jsp files that I created into my .html files. The Tomcat program I'm using allows me to emulate a client to server side lookup with post on my .html side, and get on my .jsp side. As far as your response Eames, I'm not sure what you mean by casting, as my knowledge is still beginners, but I did try for-going double and using the var int, but was return with errors. So I continued to utilize double since it worked for the arithmetic .jsp file we did in class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all `double calc` is a primitive type variable, so there is no method available because it's not a Object.

Second, even if you would declare `Double calc`(Wrapper class of double primitive)as a Object still there is no method named `toFixed()`.

You could use `java.math.BigDecimal` to achieve precision like Javascript `toFixed()`:

```
String result = String.valueOf(new BigDecimal(calc).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP));
```

Comment: I'm still rather new at writing and implementing javascript into my html documents. So I'm not aware of the BigDecimal method. I did incorporate your full path into my script and had a few return errors. The returned errors were "BigDecimal cannot be resolved to a type" and "calc cannot be resolved to a variabl" and finally "BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP cannot be resolved to a type" all on the same line where I implemented your suggestion. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: instead of ``BigDecimal`` write ``java.math.BigDecimal``... if not work feedback me

Comment: muzahidbechara I'm not sure how to feedback. Can't find it anywhere on your profile. The only error that returns back is "calc cannot be resolved to a variable" I've had this error before when I tried the .toFixed(int), but I'm not sure why... calc does exist.

Comment: Before this line you have wrote ``double calc = 0.0;``  right?

Comment: Ah, okay... so there is an order of precedence. When I placed doublel calc line above your suggestion, it performs the calculation, but it returns with 0 on the html file instead of rounding it

Comment: I've up voted your answer (though it said something about thanking me for my feedback but currently I do not have the available rep myself to directly effect the number as of yet), but I've also edited and updated the .jsp script in my original post so you can see what I've done with your help thus far.

Comment: you could accept it as answer by clicking "TIC", it doesnt need any reputation, although it extends your reputation  :)

Comment: Muzahidbechara, Thanks again for your help. I figured it out there at the end when it came back saying "calc cannot be resolved to a variable" and you responded saying that it had to be below "double calc = 0.0;" and then I did that, but it returned a value of 0 on the html file. So, then it accord to me that it was running the string with calc still at 0.0 and not running the conditions portion. So I put your suggestion under my conditions, and poof, it worked. So once again, thank you. If I could give you more rep, I totally would.

Comment: @DonaldHollamon welcome and happy to know that it helped you a bit

Comment: @DonaldHollamon I upvoted your question so you have now enough reputation to UP VOTE

Comment: Thanks for the upvote, it looks like reputation is a big thing here. I'll have to put more time into stackoverflow since I'm looking at trying to expand my knowledge in java. Unfortunately, the requirement for upvoting is 15, and I'm currently at 8 with your help. So I'll have to put more work in to get my rep up. Then hitting 15, I'll be back to upvote your answer, because it was very helpful in accomplishing what I wanted. Although what I wanted went beyond the scope of the assignment, I like learning new things, which you did.

Comment: It's always a great pleasure to share knowledge with other developers. You may face some expert with well reputation who are very strict about quality of question. DONT be frustrated, just think those responses as their moral duty and keep going by asking & answering. One more thing , REPUTATION is important to unlock features of StackOverflow which are really nice.